# connect to REST endpoint using OAuth2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to explore different options to connect to a REST endpoint using Azure Data Factory. I have the below python code which does what I am looking for but not sure if Azure Data Factory offers something out of the box to connect to the api or a way to call a custom code.

**Code:**

```
import sys
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
import json
import logging
import time     
logging.captureWarnings(True)
api_url = "https://webapi.com/api/v1/data"          
client_id = 'client'
client_secret = 'secret'     
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://webapi.com/connect/accesstoken', client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)    
client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token)
response = client.get(api_url)
data = response.json()
```

When I look at the REST linked service I don't see many authentication options

[image]

Could you please point to me on what activities to use to make OAuth2 working in Azure Data Factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use a `WebActivity` to call using POST method and get the **authentication token** before getting data from API.

Here is an example.

1. First create an `Web Activity`.
2. Select your URL that would do the authentication and get the token.
3. Set `Method` to POST.
4. Create header > `Name`: Content-Type  `Value`: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
5. Configure request body for HTTP request.

..

```
Format: grant_type=refresh_token&client_id={client_id}&client_secret=t0_0CxxxxxxxxOKyT8gWva3GPU0JxYhsQ-S1XfAIYaEYrpB&refresh_token={refresh_token}

Example: grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=HsdO3t5xxxxxxxxx0VBsbGYb&client_secret=t0_0CqU8oA5snIOKyT8gWxxxxxxxxxYhsQ-S1XfAIYaEYrpB&refresh_token={refresh_token
```

I have shown above for example, please replace with respective id and secret when you try.

[image]

As an output from this `WebActivity`, you would receive a JSON string. From which you can extract the `access_token` to further use in any request header from further activities (**REST linked service**) in the pipeline depending on your need.

You can get the access_token like below. I have assigned it to a variable for simplicity.

```
@activity('GetOauth2 token').output.access_token
```

[image]

Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#use-oauth) from official MS doc for Oauth authentication implementation for copying data.